# Building Kernel for Debian on another Machine: GRUB: Out of Memory

Tags: linux-kernel, grub2

I to an evalboard for Intel Elkhartlake.
The problem is the Plattform is not really a productive one.
It tends to get hot, has only a 16GB CFast Storage Card and 1 GB of RAM.
I installed a debian bullseye with kernel version 5.10-23 i installed the source package and tried to rebuild the kernel since the System isn't really working reliable i did the following:

```
#create workspace folder
mkdir kernel
cd kernel

#Copy Kernel Sources from target system to a more powerful Ubuntu Machine:
scp user@evb-elkhartlake:/usr/src/linux-source-5.10.tar.xz .

#extract Kernel Sources
tar -xf linux-source-5.10.tar.xz
cd linux-source-5.10

#copy running kernel config
scp user@evb-elkhartlake:/boot/config-5.10.0-23-amd64 ./.config

#changed CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="debian/certs/debian-uefi-certs.pem" to CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS=""
#changed CONFIG_BUILD_SALT="5.10.0-23-amd64" to CONFIG_BUILD_SALT="5.10.0-23-amd64-bae-mx"

make -j$(nproc)
```

This builds without a problem but when i upload and start the kernel:

```
NEW_KERNEL_PATH="/boot/vmlinuz-dev"
GRUB_CONFIG="/etc/default/grub"
KERNEL_PARAMETERS="quiet splash"  # Add any additional parameters you need
KERNEL_ENTRY="GRUB_DEFAULT=$NEW_KERNEL_PATH"

# Append kernel entry and parameters to GRUB config
sed -i "s/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=.*/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=\"$KERNEL_PARAMETERS\"/" $GRUB_CONFIG
sed -i "s|^GRUB_DEFAULT=.*|$KERNEL_ENTRY|" $GRUB_CONFIG

update-grub
```

After rebooting GRUB halts with error message: Out of Memory

I then checked the kernel size. it is big.(vmlinuz-dev compared to vmlinuz-5.10.0-23-amd64)

```
ls -alh
total 670M
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Aug  9 18:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 4.0K Aug  8 17:03 ..
...
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6.8M Jul 28 00:17 vmlinuz-5.10.0-23-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6.8M Aug  8 18:19 vmlinuz-5.10.0-23-amd64-official
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 6.6M Sep 23  2021 vmlinuz-5.10.0-8-amd64
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 533M Aug  9 18:03 vmlinuz-dev
```

I uploaded the Kernel config to: https://pastebin.com/p4CtiS4N

Can any one tell me what can cause this kernel size on basically a rebuild?
I never build debian on a non Debian system before.
(Can't change os because we need to use approved images from our it department.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From where did you take the file you placed to `/boot/vmlinuz-dev`?
Is it the same file as  `(kernel source dir)/arch/x86/boot/bzImage`?

What does `file /boot/vmlinuz-dev` say?

You may have accidentally grabbed the version that includes all the debugging symbols. It might be useful when analyzing crash dumps and doing other debugging, but the primary kernel image file definitely should not be that big.

Comment: omg thx i copied the vmlinuz directly from the source base folder (kernel source dir)/vmlinuz wich isn't the bzImage.